# Apache Ant: copy files using regex

Tags: ant

I have the following code which doesnt work.
it gives me an error **"filename doesn't support the regex attribute"**

```
<target name="release">
 <copy todir="${build.path}">
     <fileset dir="${src.path}" includes="**/*.sql">
        <filename regex="${regex}"/>
      </fileset>
 </copy>
</target>
```

I am trying to copy certain files using a predefined regular expression for the file names.

Is there any way to solve this problem.

I have files like

```
BR2-01.00.01-sns.sql
BR2-01.00.01-entrata.sql
BR2-02.00.02-mcd.sql
BR2-03.03.01-bg.sql
BR2-03.00.03-rbs.sql
BR2-04.02.01-custom.sql
```

I just want to provide a regex to copy files as per my regex
Example

```
.*\-[0][1-2]\.[0][0]\.[0-9][0-9]\-.*
```

should copy only

```
BR2-01.00.01-sns.sql
BR2-01.00.01-entrata.sql
BR2-02.00.02-mcd.sql
```

Comment: What is the value of `${regex}`?

Comment: regex can be something like .*[0][1-2]\.[0][0-9]\.[0][0-9].*

Comment: Could you provide an example of a file that you would like to be copied? And, preferably, the regex you are using for that.

Comment: It works for me without any problem. Maybe your properties (`${regex}`, etc/) are incorrectly defined. Try to echo them and see if they have proper values.

Comment: it gives me an error 'filename doesn't support the "regex" attribute'

Comment: Maybe old Ant version is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're using Ant 1.7.x, you should update your ant version.
The regex feature for `org.apache.ant.tools.ant.types.selectors.FilenameSelector` is available
 for >= Ant 1.8.

Comment: Thanks, Yah I was using 1.7.1